# Assigning tasks to minimize cost

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a set of jobs that must be done on a given day in sequence. $J_1, J_2, J_3$, with deadlines $D_1, D_2, D_3$. There are three workers $W_1, W_2, W_3$ that can execute the tasks each one with varying effects of proficiency $V_1, V_2, V_3$, so a highly proficient worker will do the task in less time, but will also incur a higher cost $C_1, C_2, C_3$. I want to figure out the constraints for a linear program that will execute all tasks within their respective deadline, while minimizing my costs.

I have:
$x_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if job $i$ executed by worker $j$},\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

and one of the constraints I believe should be the fact that I need to choose one, and only, one worker to do the job, so maybe:

$$\sum_{j=1}^3 X_{ij}=1 \quad \text{for $i\in J$}$$

The next constraints that we should consider is obviously the deadline; time to execute previous jobs plus time for current job, since they must be done in sequence (production line), so maybe:

$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 T_{ij}X_{ij}\le D_i$$

$$ T_{ij}, i \in J, j \in W $$ is the time that worker $j$ needs to execute job $i$.

Are these constraints correct, or do they make sense in the first place?
If not what should I consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the deadline constraint as given makes no sense. The summation over $i$ is incorrect.

Given the possibility of a worker doing multiple jobs, one possible fix is as follows. Introduce new variables $L_{ij} \ge 0$, representing the cumulative time worker $j$ spends on any of jobs 1 through $i$ (inclusive) assigned to worker $j$. The values of $L$ are determined by the following constraints (for all workers $j$):
\begin{align*}
L_{1j} & =T_{1j}X_{2j}\\
L_{2j} & =L_{1j}+T_{2j}X_{2j}\\
L_{3j} & =L_{2j}+T_{3j}X_{3j}.
\end{align*}
To enforce the deadlines, add the following constraints for all $j$:
\begin{align*}
L_{1j} & \le D_{1j}\\
L_{2j} & \le D_{2j}+T_{1j}(1-X_{2j})\\
L_{3j} & \le D_{3j}+(T_{1j}+T_{2j})(1-X_{3j}).
\end{align*}
Those constraints ensure that a worker finishes a task by the task's deadline *if* the worker is doing the task. You already have constraints to ensure that each task is done by a single worker.

Answer (score 0):

The first constraint should be for $i\in J$ instead of $i\in W$.

The second constraint is missing $i\in J$, and you should not mix $\sum_i$ and $i\in J$.  It might help to write this as three separate constraints, one per job.  Also, you have not used $V_i$ anywhere.

Comment: I fixed the first constraint (and an obvious typo elsewhere). Meanwhile, it is unspecified whether a worker can do more than one job. If so, and assuming the jobs must be done in the order 1, 2, 3, the deadline constraint is incorrect. If not, another constraint is needed to limit each worker to a single job.

Comment: @prubin a worker can do more than one job, even all of them. The problem is probably not well defined, I created it on my own because I am reading a book on LP. How should the deadline constraint be fixed?